# why does NSIS sets the target to default INSTDIR?

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to create an exe installer for a 32-bit application, which would create shortcut for my application as well. I'm using NSIS to build an installer and I'm successful in build the installer. When I run the .exe on a 64-bit windows OS, it creates the necessary folders, updates the Registry and creates a shortcut on the desktop too. However, when I check the properties of the shorcut on the desktop created, the "start-in" parameter is correct. However, the target parameter is wrong. i.e. I use:

createshortcut "$DESKTOP\shortcut.lnk" "$INSTDIR\bin\app.exe" ""

where INSTDIR = programfiles

The start-in is set correctly to: C:\program files(x86)....
I was expecting the target to be the same.

But, the target is set to: C:\program files....

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why are you using an empty optional parameter?

Comment: I don't have any parameter to pass. Will that affect setting the target?

Comment: There are several optional parameters, only setting one of them to empty is pretty random but it should not affect the .lnk

Comment: Also, I'm not too sure, if using quotes for the InstallDir would make any diff. Currently, I'm using:

InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES\app\java

Comment: Could you post a minimal example script that reproduces the issue, something like http://pastebin.com/5Ze7SW4L maybe?

Answer (score 1):

`MessageBox` $INSTDIR before creating the shortcut, make sure it is `C:\program files(x86)\...`

Are you calling DisableX64FSRedirection (x64.nsh)?

The start-in/working directory comes from the last call to SetOutPath.

I think NSIS passes the strings pretty much untouched to the shell, you can use the [logging build](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Special_Builds#Advanced_logging) to see the string before it is passed to [IShellLink::SetPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Messagebox does display the path to program files (x86)\... But the target on the link file created on the desktop is being pointed to program files\....

Comment: @Ashok try replacing $INSTDIR with just C:\program files(x86)\

Comment: That does the magic. So, INSTDIR is not setting to the program files(x86)? But, it does show when I display using Messagebox. How to write the generic solution then?

Comment: Does this mean, INSTDIR is not reading the value properly from InstallDir? Any idea how to work around this problem?

Comment: You said messagebox $instdir displayed the correct value. What happens if you do StrCpy $instdir "C:\program files(x86)" and then createshortcut "$DESKTOP\shortcut.lnk" "$INSTDIR\bin\app.exe" (or even Strcpy $instdir $programfiles) ?

Comment: Anders,
 Sorry for the delay. I've tried setting $INSTDIR with Program files(x86)/ before creating the shortcut. It sets the start-in parameter of the shortcut to program files (x86)\.. but the target still points to program files\..

Comment: Anders, One more question that I have is: How would NSIS detect the $PROGRAMFILES? i.e., will it get the Environment variable PROGRAMFILES? or is there any predefined variable set for NSIS which would identify, PROGRAMFILES as program files (x86) for windows 7?

Comment: @Ashok It reads the registry IIRC. BTW, the thing you are creating a shortcut to must exist before you can create the shortcut...

Comment: I'm positive that the shortcut target file exists before I create the link. I'm doubtful if it has something to do with the file/directory permissions? I ran a quick check and found Program files (x86) has read-only permission. Will this affect the installation? 
P.S: the installation fails only when I try to install under Program files (x86)

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment, as the other locations where I've tried installing also had only read-only permission. So, I believe this has nothing to do with the file permission?